# Appmenuitem & SetupEntityAccess relation for creating app launcher for connected apps

Tags: soql, connected-apps, identity

For all records with type='ConnectedApplication' in appmenuItem object, some information should be available in SetupEntityAccess object but I am not able to find any data.

Reference: Last query on following link
https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_setupentityaccess.htm

What I am looking for is list of ConnectedApplication accessible to a particular profile in salesforce. Any help ? How can I link records in appmenuItem  and SetupEntityAccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer? You can't: https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_setupentityaccess.htm

This query gets you your ConnectedApplication records from SetupEntityAccess:

```
SELECT Id, Parent.Profile.Name, SetupEntityId 
  FROM SetupEntityAccess 
 WHERE SetupEntityType = 'ConnectedApplication'
```

And this query gets you your AppMenuItem records:

```
SELECT ApplicationId,  Description, Id, Label, Name 
  FROM AppMenuItem 
 WHERE Type = 'ConnectedApplication'
```

You can use VLOOKUP() in Excel to merge these lists on AppMenuItem.ApplicationId - or you can do a little magic in Apex.

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah got it, it was not available in version 30, so not able to find this earlier.